# Prob. 4, Sec. 25, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Is every connected subset of a locally path connected space not path connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Here is Prob. 4, Sec. 25, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $X$ be a locally path-connected topological space. Let $A$ be a non-empty connected subspace  of $X$. Then $A$ is path-connected.

Proof:

> Let $C$ be the component of $X$ that intersects $A$. Then $C$ is also a path component of $X$ because $X$ is locally path connected. Moreover, $A \subset C$.

> Thus, if $x , y \in A$, then $x, y \in C$ and since $C$ is path connected,  by definition there is a path in $X$ from $x$ to $y$, showing that $A$ is path connected.

Is there anything wrong with this proof?

If so, what? If not, then do we need $A$ to be open, as Munkres hypothesises?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott, can you please answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\mathbb R^2$, $A=(\{0\}\times \mathbb R)\cup\{\,(x,\sin\frac1x)\mid x>0\,\}$ and note that $A$ is not path connected. Check where your proof attempt fails with this example.

Comment: I've thought but haven't been able to figure out where lies the problem. It's so confusing!

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ lies in the path component $C$ of $X$, it means, by definition, that any two points in $A$ can be connected by a path in $X$. However, this does not imply that these two points can also be connected by a path in $A$. Therefore, $A$ is not necessarily path-connected.

In other words, a subspace $A$ of the path-connected space $C$ is not necessarily path-connected.